# How invoke sendKeys() method for Integer values using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium, value-of

```
driver.findElementById("com.devere.development:id/et_code_1").sendKeys(Keys.valueOf(1);

driver.findElementById("com.devere.development:id/et_code_1").sendKeys(Keys.valueOf(1);
```

Answer (score 3):

`sendKeys()` will only take String as an argument.

However, if you want to convert a string into integer, you could use this code :

```
String str = "1234";
int foo = Integer.parseInt(str);
```

for conversion from Interger to String, you could use :

```
String.valueOf(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

To invoke `sendKeys()` with `Integer` values you need to use **`String.valueOf()`** method to convert the `integer` to `String` and can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);     
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
  int myInt = 1234567890;
  driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(String.valueOf(myInt));
  ```

If your usecase is to send numbers e.g. **1234567890** you can invoke `sendKeys()` with the desired `Character Sequence` i.e. **`1234567890`** and the element validation functions will validate the value on it's own if it was an **integer** and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);     
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
  driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("1234567890");
  ```

Broswer Snapshot:

[image: sendKeys_integer]